# What is the best way to animate buttons?

Tags: ios, iphone, animation

I want to make a slide-out menu in my iPhone app similar to [THIS](https://dribbble.com/shots/1193368-Decision-App?list=searches&offset=10) image

For the menu button, I would like to add an animation to the menu button when pressed almost identical to [THIS](https://dribbble.com/shots/1625075-Animated-Menu-Icon)

My question is: *What is the best way to perform the animation?*

1. Do I create a GIF image and then break the GIF down to its individual images and then simply play the array of images one after the other when the button is pressed to replicate the GIF?
2. Do I draw the 3 lines of the menu button as in Code Sample 1. below and when the button is pressed I animate the lines as in Code Sample 2. 
   I can draw the 3 lines representing the menu icon on the screen and then when the menu button is pressed, move the top and bottom lines towards the middle line. When they reach the middle line, remove one of the lines and then spin the 2 remaining lines to +45 and -45 degrees to give the X appearance

*Code Samples only shown as examples and not actual implemented code

Code Sample 1.

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.bounds.size.width, 1)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:lineView];
[lineView release];
```

Code Sample 2.

```
+(void)rotateViewLikeCircle:(UIView*)view rotation:(int)numberOfRotation 
{
    CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180)];
    rotationAnimation.duration = 0.75;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = numberOfRotation;
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    [view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked your question and started working on the method you described and learnt lots of things in the process. I am enclosing my code. But there is a small problem, in the last part of switching OFF animation. It is slightly jerking, but it will look like as part of animation considering the size of button is small and duration of animation is very less.

Do let me know, if you can improve my code on that jerking part.

```
@interface YourViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CALayer *layer1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CALayer *layer2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CALayer *layer3;

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isBtnStateOn;

@end

@implementation YourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createBtnSetup];
}

- (void)createBtnSetup
{
    self.layer1 = [self createLayerWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 50, 60, 10)];
    self.layer2 = [self createLayerWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 80, 60, 10)];
    self.layer3 = [self createLayerWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 110, 60, 10)];

    // Place transparent button on top of layers.
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 50, 60, 70)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

- (CALayer *)createLayerWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
    [layer setFrame:frame];
    [layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [layer setCornerRadius:5.f];
    [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];

    return layer;
}

- (void)btnTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (self.isBtnStateOn == NO) {
        self.isBtnStateOn = YES;
        [self animateBtnToOnState];
    }
    else {
        self.isBtnStateOn = NO;
        [self animateBtnToOffState];
    }
}

- (void)animateBtnToOnState
{
    CABasicAnimation *translateAnim = [self getTranslationAnimationFrom:@(0) to:@(self.layer2.frame.origin.y - self.layer1.frame.origin.y) timingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn duration:0.5f beginTime:0.f fillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [self.layer1 addAnimation:translateAnim forKey:@"translateAnimation"];

    translateAnim = [self getTranslationAnimationFrom:@(0) to:@(self.layer2.frame.origin.y - self.layer3.frame.origin.y) timingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn duration:0.5f beginTime:0.f fillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [self.layer3 addAnimation:translateAnim forKey:@"translateAnimation"];

    CABasicAnimation *opacity = [self getOpacityAnimationFromValue:@(1.f) toValue:@(0.f) timingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear duration:0.f beginTime:0.4f fillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [self.layer2 addAnimation:opacity forKey:@"opacityAnimation"];

    CABasicAnimation *rotation = [self getRotationAnimationWithFromAngle:@(0) toAngle:@(M_PI_2 + M_PI_4 + M_PI_4 / 5) timingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear duration:0.5f beginTime:0.5f fillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [self.layer1 addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];

    rotation = [self getRotationAnimationWithFromAngle:@(0) toAngle:@(M_PI_4) timingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear duration:0.5f beginTime:0.5f fillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [self.layer3 addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];

    CABasicAnimation *afterRotation = [self getRotationAnimationWithFromAngle:@(M_PI_2 + M_PI_4 + M_PI_4 / 5) toAngle:@(M_PI_2 + M_PI_4) timingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn duration:0.3f beginTime:1.f fillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [self.layer1 addAnimation:afterRotation forKey:@"afterRotationAnimation"];
}

- (void)animateBtnToOffState
{
    CABasicAnimation *rotation = [self getRotationAnimationWithFromAngle:@(M_PI_2 + M_PI_4) toAngle:@(0) timingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn duration:0.5f beginTime:0.f fillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [self.layer1 addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];

    rotation = [self getRotationAnimationWithFromAngle:@(M_PI_4) toAngle:@(0) timingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn duration:0.5f beginTime:0.f fillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [self.layer3 addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];

    CABasicAnimation *opacity = [self getOpacityAnimationFromValue:@(0.f) toValue:@(1.f) timingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear duration:0.f beginTime:0.5f fillMode:kCAFillModeBackwards];
    [self.layer2 addAnimation:opacity forKey:@"opacityAnimation"];

    CABasicAnimation *translateAnim = [self getTranslationAnimationFrom:@(self.layer2.frame.origin.y - self.layer1.frame.origin.y) to:@(-0.25 * (self.layer2.frame.origin.y - self.layer1.frame.origin.y)) timingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut duration:0.5f beginTime:0.5f fillMode:kCAFillModeBackwards];
    [self.layer1 addAnimation:translateAnim forKey:@"translateAnimation"];

    translateAnim = [self getTranslationAnimationFrom:@(self.layer2.frame.origin.y - self.layer3.frame.origin.y) to:@(-0.25 * (self.layer2.frame.origin.y - self.layer3.frame.origin.y)) timingFunction:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut duration:0.5f beginTime:0.5f fillMode:kCAFillModeBackwards];
    [self.layer3 addAnimation:translateAnim forKey:@"translateAnimation"];
}

- (CABasicAnimation *)getTranslationAnimationFrom:(NSNumber *)fromValue to:(NSNumber *)toValue timingFunction:(NSString *)timingFunction duration:(CGFloat)duration beginTime:(CGFloat)beginTime fillMode:(NSString *)fillMode
{
    CABasicAnimation *translate = [self getBasicAnimationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y" fromValue:fromValue toValue:toValue timingFunction:timingFunction duration:duration beginTime:beginTime fillMode:fillMode];
    return translate;
}

- (CABasicAnimation *)getRotationAnimationWithFromAngle:(NSNumber *)fromAngle toAngle:(NSNumber *)toAngle timingFunction:(NSString *)timingFunction duration:(CGFloat)duration beginTime:(CGFloat)beginTime fillMode:(NSString *)fillMode
{
    CABasicAnimation *rotation = [self getBasicAnimationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z" fromValue:fromAngle toValue:toAngle timingFunction:timingFunction duration:duration beginTime:beginTime fillMode:fillMode];
    return rotation;
}

- (CABasicAnimation *)getOpacityAnimationFromValue:(NSNumber *)fromValue toValue:(NSNumber *)toValue timingFunction:(NSString *)timingFunction duration:(CGFloat)duration beginTime:(CGFloat)beginTime fillMode:(NSString *)fillMode
{
    CABasicAnimation *opacity = [self getBasicAnimationWithKeyPath:@"opacity" fromValue:fromValue toValue:toValue timingFunction:timingFunction duration:duration beginTime:beginTime fillMode:fillMode];
    return opacity;
}

- (CABasicAnimation *)getBasicAnimationWithKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath fromValue:(NSNumber *)fromValue toValue:(NSNumber *)toValue timingFunction:(NSString *)timingFunction duration:(CGFloat)duration beginTime:(CGFloat)beginTime fillMode:(NSString *)fillMode
{
    CABasicAnimation *basicAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:keyPath];
    [basicAnimation setFromValue:fromValue];
    [basicAnimation setToValue:toValue];
    [basicAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:timingFunction]];
    [basicAnimation setRepeatCount:0.f];
    [basicAnimation setDuration:duration];
    [basicAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [basicAnimation setCumulative:YES];
    [basicAnimation setFillMode:fillMode];
    [basicAnimation setBeginTime:(CACurrentMediaTime() + beginTime)];
    return basicAnimation;
}

@end
```

Comment: WOW user1190882! Thanks a whole bunch for this. I will try this as soon as possible and let you know how I get on. Really appreciate it. I see also you went with the creating rectangles as lines and then animating them vs. playing GIF images. Looking forward to see how this work.

Comment: Managed to get around to trying your code tonight and it works like a charm. Like you say there is a very small jerk at the end but nothing too serious. I will see can I improve on this and post code here but for now Ill accept this as the answer. Thanks for the great help.

Comment: Sorted out the small jerk. The values in the CABasicAnimation *translateAnim .... to:@(-0.25 * (self.layer2.frame.origin.y... in the - (void)animateBtnToOffState method were slightly too big. I set them to be ... to:@(-0.01 * (self.layer2.frame.origin.y and it sorted the jerk at the end out. There is no "spring" to the end of the animation but thats perfect for my needs. Thanks again user1190882